# Increment all sequences in Postgresql DB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, postgresql-12

I migrating a PostgreSQL DB using AWS DMS. The source DB is on Aurora Postgres 10.xx and the target DB is on Aurora Postgres 12.xx.

Since DMS does not sync sequences, so I am using the following query (on the target DB) to create Dynamic sql queries which will increment my sequences by max_value of the associated column + 1000:

```
SELECT 
    'SELECT SETVAL(' ||
       quote_literal(quote_ident(sequence_namespace.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(class_sequence.relname)) ||
       ', COALESCE(MAX(' ||quote_ident(pg_attribute.attname)|| '), 1)+ 1000 ) FROM ' || -- Buffer of 1000
       quote_ident(table_namespace.nspname)|| '.'||quote_ident(class_table.relname)|| ';'
FROM pg_depend 
    INNER JOIN pg_class AS class_sequence
        ON class_sequence.oid = pg_depend.objid 
            AND class_sequence.relkind = 'S'
    INNER JOIN pg_class AS class_table
        ON class_table.oid = pg_depend.refobjid
    INNER JOIN pg_attribute 
        ON pg_attribute.attrelid = class_table.oid
            AND pg_depend.refobjsubid = pg_attribute.attnum
    INNER JOIN pg_namespace as table_namespace
        ON table_namespace.oid = class_table.relnamespace
    INNER JOIN pg_namespace AS sequence_namespace
        ON sequence_namespace.oid = class_sequence.relnamespace
    where sequence_namespace.nspname='public' -- This is the schema name
ORDER BY sequence_namespace.nspname, class_sequence.relname;
```

This returns a total of 15 SQL statements which means 15 sequences in total in the public schema.

Now when I do a `\ds public.*` on the same database, it gives me 25 sequences. I am not able to figure out why the SELECT query is not able to pick up all the 25 sequences.

Can someone please help here?

Thanks

Comment: Without any details other than the query, all I can do is guess. Most likely 10 of the sequences aren't being returned by the query because no columns depend on them.

Comment: I can see all the Missing sequences in the Default value of columns when a do a \d <Table_Name>. This means that the default values of the columns depend on the sequence.

Comment: @JohnH -- I see one difference. The sequence which shows up in the SELECT query have "ALTER SEQUENCE public.seq_11_name OWNED BY public.table_name.ColumnName;". and the one which does not show up in the select query does not have the "Alter Sequence query" however it has something like: "CREATE TABLE public.Table (
    Column_Name bigint DEFAULT nextval('public.missing_seq_name'::regclass) NOT NULL,......." . 
Does it make any difference?

Comment: That's definitely a clue. Remove the table and column dependency portions of the query to see if that returns  all of the sequences reported by `\ds *.public`. If it does, then add back the dependency portions using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with sufficient columns in the select list to determine which joins are unsatisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query only returns sequences that are owned by a table column:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq OWNED BY tab.id;
```

The other sequences seem not to have such a relationship to a table column.